Is there any solution to the below Cucumber TestNG runner file?
I started learning Cucumber for selenium. I tried the below code. I am getting error and unable to catch it. kindly help me to resolve this. The Stepdefinition file is correct and the Test Runner code also correct. It is launching the webpage but in desired username section its adding the username as  instead of the proper username which I have mentioned in the example. For the password section it is typing the password correctly. Only issue with the username I guess.
Here is the below code:
package automation.StepDefinition;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.Assert;

import automation.pageObjects.LandingPage;
import automation.pageObjects.cartPage;
import automation.pageObjects.checkOutPage;
import automation.pageObjects.confirmationPage;
import automation.pageObjects.productCatalogue;
import automation.testComponents.BaseClass;
import io.cucumber.java.en.And;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;

public class StepDefinition extends BaseClass {
    LandingPage lp;
    productCatalogue pc;
    checkOutPage cop;
    cartPage cp;
    confirmationPage conP;
    
    @Given("I landed on the eCommerce homePage")
    public void I_landed_on_the_eCommerce_homePage() throws IOException
    {
        lp=launchApp();
    }
    @Given("^Logged in with username (.+) and password (.+)$")
    public void Logged_in_with_username_and_password(String userName, String password)
    {
        pc=lp.loginPageActions(userName, password);
    }
    @When("^I add product (.+) to the cart$")
    public void I_add_product_to_the_cart(String productName)
    {
        List<WebElement> products = pc.listOfProducts();
        pc.addProdtoCart(productName);
    }
    @And("^Go to checkout with the product (.+) and submit the order$")
    public void Go_to_checkout_with_the_product_and_submit_the_order(String productName)
    {
        cp = lp.goToCart();
        cp.cartItemsList(productName);
        cop = cp.checkOutButton();
        cop.enterCountry();
        cop.selectCountryFromList();
        conP = cop.submitOrder();
    }
    @Then("Then Confirmation message {string} message will display on ConfirmationPage")
    public void confirmation_message_display(String string) 
    {
        String getMessage = conP.confirmMessage();
        // Assert.assertTrue(pName);
        Assert.assertTrue(getMessage.equalsIgnoreCase(string)); 
    }

}

Here is the error:
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.7.1
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Jul 30, 2024 2:09:14 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 126, returning the closest version; found: 125; Please update to a Selenium version that supports CDP version 126
FAILED: io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.runScenario("Positive test for submitting the order", "Title of your feature")
        Runs Cucumber Scenarios
io.cucumber.testng.UndefinedStepException: The step 'Logged in with userName <name> and password "Ansuman1@3"' and 1 other step(s) are undefined.
You can implement these steps using the snippet(s) below:

@Given("Logged in with userName <name> and password {string}")
public void logged_in_with_user_name_name_and_password(String string) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
}
@Then("Confirmation message {string} message will display on ConfirmationPage")
public void confirmation_message_message_will_display_on_confirmation_page(String string) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
}

    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.TestCaseResultObserver.assertTestCasePassed(TestCaseResultObserver.java:69)
    at io.cucumber.testng.TestCaseResultObserver.assertTestCasePassed(TestCaseResultObserver.java:23)
    at io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.lambda$runScenario$1(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:133)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.lambda$runTestCase$5(CucumberExecutionContext.java:137)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.RethrowingThrowableCollector.executeAndThrow(RethrowingThrowableCollector.java:23)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:137)
    at io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:129)
    at io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.runScenario(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:35)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:677)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:221)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:969)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:194)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:829)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:437)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:431)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:391)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:330)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1256)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1176)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1099)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1067)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:293)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:91)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 0, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


I tried to run the Cucumber test but it failed.

Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and pay extra attention to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Right now it is impossible to help you because your question contains to many details that don't matter for your problem and but none of the details that do. You can solve both problems by making a minimal reproducible example.
